# How to use Trampoline IOS

Tags: iphone, ios

I was looking for this on google and I found some articles on it They say it is used for  HigherOrderMessaging and I tried to read the code to but everything was over my head can any body give simple example of it how we can use them? They were saying its used for passing returned object from method to another object. And another question when I develop apps never came situation where I need to use something like this.

Answer (score 2):

In Objective-C, a trampoline is an object returned by a method that exposes some kind of message interface. When messages are received, it bounces the message on to another object.

**Example One:**

Return a proxy of a service client. When methods are invoked on the proxy, it first checks if the user has permission to proceed.

**Example Two:**

Make all the objects in an array do something:

```
[[windowsArray do] setHidesOnDeactivate:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks for answer jasper I do understand little bit Ill accept your answer but for now lets just keep this discussion go further  :)

Comment: You're welcome. . hopefully a very detailed answer will turn up.

Comment: Yes lets hope for this. hey jasper is this thing very help full? is there come situation where we really need this? or we wont be able to move ahead?

Comment: Its just a design pattern. There is usually more than on approach to a problem. One example where its indispensable is in key-value observing - dispatching back to the main thread: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ReceptionistPattern/ReceptionistPattern.html

Comment: what is this TYPHOON ? whats the use of it?

Comment: Nothing to do with this question ..  Why not read the docs and then ask a specific question, if you don't understand something.